# getElementById + getElementsByTagName gives Type error in javascript console

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

So I am trying to create a random generator that shows one out of many hidden images + one out of many hidden DIVs.

For the images it is working alright as they are the only ones on the page, but as soon as I try to selected certain div tags inside another div tag I get the error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined  "

I have 9 divs in a `<div id="text">`. This is my javascript code, that I am trying to run :

```
function randomString() {

    var chars = "123456789";
    var string_length = 1;
    var randomstring = '';
    var x = document.getElementById("text").getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }

    for(var j=0; j<8 ;j++) {

        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].style.opacity="0";
        document.getElementById("text").getElementsByTagName("div")[j].style.display="none";
    }

    switch (randomstring*1) {

        case 1: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.opacity="1";
                x[0].style.display="block"; break;
        case 2: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].style.opacity="1";
                x[1].style.display="block"; break;
        case 3: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[2].style.opacity="1";
                x[2].style.display="block"; break;
        case 4: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[3].style.opacity="1";
                x[3].style.display="block"; break;
        case 5: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[4].style.opacity="1";
                x[4].style.display="block"; break;
        case 6: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[5].style.opacity="1";
                x[5].style.display="block"; break;
        case 7: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[6].style.opacity="1";
                x[6].style.display="block"; break;
        case 8: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[7].style.opacity="1";
                x[7].style.display="block"; break;
        case 9: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[8].style.opacity="1";
                x[8].style.display="block"; break;
    }

    document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;

}
```

And this is what I have in the HTML :

```
 <DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MTB Tricks Randomiser</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="randomizer.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="randomizer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Click the button to find out what your trick for today is!
            <br> (If you dare...)
        </h3>
    </header>
    <form name="randform">
        <input type="button" value="Create Random String" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
    </form>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="images">
            <img src="images/a.jpg" id="firstimage"/>
            <img src="images/b.jpg" id="secondimage" />
            <img src="images/c.jpg" id="thirdimage"/>
            <img src="images/d.jpg" id="fourthimage"/>
            <img src="images/e.jpg" id="fifthimage"/>
            <img src="images/f.jpg" id="sixthimage"/>
        </div>
        <div id="text">
            <div id="textone">
                    a
            </div>
            <div id="texttwo">
                    b
            </div>
            <div id="textthree">
                    c
            </div>
            <div id="textfour">
                    d
            </div>
            <div id="textfive">
                    e
            </div>
            <div id="textsix">
                    f
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have 8 div tags in your html?

Comment: I am trying to do it without getElementById("textone") then texttwo... as it will be too long and unprofessional. Sorry if something looks quite bad written, I have been attending courses only for three months

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/hegpm/), is that browser specific problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it would error out in the `switch` statement for cases 7 - 9 because there are only 6 images in the HTML.  As in, a line like `document.getElementsByTagName("img")[8].style.opacity="1";` would fail.

Comment: Thanks, this too + the answer below which was correct, I don't know why it got disliked. All work fine, thanks everybody! This site has helped me so much by far...best community ever! :)

Comment: They're not showing because of `.style.display="none";` you should change this to whatever style you wish for your returned divs. Frustrating when folks downvote without explanation.